# google script using checkboxes like radio buttons

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, checkbox, triggers

I am trying to use checkboxes like radio buttons in Google Sheets.  I started with the helpful script at https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/radio-buttons-in-google-sheets/ But it only does rows, which unfortunately won't work for me.  Kudos to Ben for that code too.

So using Ben's code as a starting place I want to have the app uncheck boxes that are part of a group and only leave the selected one checked.

I have set the demo up like a multiple choice questions and answers things, with two questions (as in screen shot below:

[image: screenshot]

my code is:

```
/**
 * onEdit to uncheck checkboxes as required
 */
function onEdit(e) {
  // get event object data: sheet name, row number and column number
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sheet.getName()!='questions'){return}  // makes sure we only impact the one sheet we want to adjust
  const row = e.range.rowStart; 
  console.log(row);
  if (row < 8) {
    var block1 = row;
  }
  else if(row > 8 && row < 14) {
    var block2 = row;
  }
  switch(block1) {
    // case when row 3 is checked
    case 1:
      sheet.getRange("B4:B7").uncheck();
      break;
    // case when row 4 is checked
    case 2:
      sheet.getRangeList(["B3","B5:B7"]).uncheck();
      break;
    // case when row 5 is checked
    case 3:
      sheet.getRangeList(["B3:B4","B6:B7"]).uncheck();
      break;
    // case when row 6 is checked
    case 4:    
      sheet.getRangeList(["B3:B5","B7"]).uncheck();
      break;   
    // case when row 7 is checked
    case 5:
      sheet.getRange("B3:B6").uncheck();
      break;
    // cell is outside of rows 3 to 7
    default:
      return;
  }
  switch (block2) {
    // case when row 10 is checked
    case 1:
      sheet.getRange("B11:B13").uncheck();
      break;
    // case when row 11 is checked
    case 2:
      sheet.getRangeList(["B10","B12:B13"]).uncheck();
      break;
    // case when row 12 is checked
    case 3:
      sheet.getRangeList(["B10:B11","B13"]).uncheck();
      break;
    // case when row 13 is checked
    case 4:    
      sheet.getRangeList(["B10:B12"]).uncheck();
      break;
    // cell is outside of rows 3 to 7
    default:
      return;
  }
}
```

Note that I have multiple sheets in the workbook, which therefore requires the test at line 7.

Currently the only cell that works the way I would expect is B7.

Banged my head for a bit on this, so reaching out for some guidance.

Comment: OK I have part of it working :-)  My case numbers were out in the top block.  Still working on block 2..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test the region ...

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var s = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = e.source.getActiveRange();
  if(s.getName()!='questions'){return}
  if(r.getColumn()!=2){return}
  var col = 2;
  var region = r.getDataRegion()
  var begin = region.getRow()+1;
  var height = region.getNumRows()-1; 
  var row = r.getRow();
  if (r.getValue()) {
    var values = s.getRange(begin,col,height,1).getValues()
    for (var i=0;i<values.length;i++){
      values[i][0]=false
    }
    values[row-begin][0]=true
    s.getRange(begin,col,height,1).setValues(values)
  }
}
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14vJjimVVfd_-G_M2sT7m1CjBr-rLaVhyYW0e622VDsE/copy
[image]

Comment: Thank you.  This is an amazing support system to a gumby developer like me. I trust and hope this is also to the benefit of others as I have seen requests for this elsewhere. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using switch statements for each question, I created a function that worked for any box in Col B (you can change to which ever column fits your needs).  You don't have to create a separate switch statement for each question.

**How It Works**

onEdit() checks if the edited cell is in col 2 of your target sheet, and that the box was checked (set to true).

Then it looks up to find the first cell in this question group and then looks down to find the last cell in the question group.

Then it iterates through all of the row numbers in that question set, and unchecks any boxes that aren't the edited cell.

There is a caveat - the row with the question in it has to have something in it for the function to find the top of the question range.  See Below

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

function onEdit(e){
   let cell = e.range;
   let value = e.value;
   let sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
   
   Logger.log(cell.getA1Notation()+"  "+sheet.getName() + " "+ value);
   
   let col = cell.getColumn()

   if(col === 2 && sheet.getName() === "Question" && value === "TRUE") {
    
    // get the row numbers of the top and bottom check boxes in this question set
    let topRow = cell.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).getRow();
    let bottomRow = cell.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow();
    
    // get the number of rows in this question set, the + before the variables forces
    // app script to treat them as a number.  
    let numOfRows = +bottomRow - +topRow +1;
   
    Logger.log("Top Row: "+topRow + " bottom row:  "+bottomRow+" number of rows: " + numOfRows);

    // loop through each box in the question set and uncheck any that weren't the edited cell
    for (var i = 0; i < numOfRows; i++){
     let box = sheet.getRange(+topRow + +i, 2);
     let boxA1 = box.getA1Notation();
      Logger.log(boxA1);
      
      if (boxA1 !== cell.getA1Notation()){
        Logger.log("Box does not equal cell");
        box.uncheck();
      }
    }
   }
}
```

Here is the image of my test sheet:

[image]

Comment: SMART!  I love it.   Much easier to implement as I have 25 blocks to do.  Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Got it.  Code below:

```
/**
 * onEdit to uncheck checkboxes as required
 */
function onEdit(e) {
  // get event object data: sheet name, row number and column number
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sheet.getName()!='questions'){return}  // makes sure we only impact the one sheet we want to adjust
  const row = e.range.rowStart; 
  console.log(row);
  if (row < 8) {
    var block1 = row;
    var loopid=1;
  }
  else if( 8 > row < 14) {
    var block2 = row;
    var loopid=2;
  }
  if (loopid== 1) {
    switch(block1) {
      // case when row 3 is checked
      case 3:
        sheet.getRange("B4:B7").uncheck();
        break;
      // case when row 4 is checked
      case 4:
        sheet.getRangeList(["B3","B5:B7"]).uncheck();
        break;
      // case when row 5 is checked
      case 5:
        sheet.getRangeList(["B3:B4","B6:B7"]).uncheck();
        break;
      // case when row 6 is checked
      case 6:    
        sheet.getRangeList(["B3:B5","B7"]).uncheck();
        break;   
      // case when row 7 is checked
      case 7:
        sheet.getRange("B3:B6").uncheck();
        break;
      // cell is outside of rows 3 to 7
      default:
        return;
    }
  }
  if (loopid==2) {
    switch (block2) {
      // case when row 10 is checked
      case 10:
        sheet.getRange("B11:B13").uncheck();
        break;
      // case when row 11 is checked
      case 11:
        sheet.getRangeList(["B10","B12:B13"]).uncheck();
        break;
      // case when row 12 is checked
      case 12:
        sheet.getRangeList(["B10:B11","B13"]).uncheck();
        break;
      // case when row 13 is checked
      case 13:    
        sheet.getRange(["B10:B12"]).uncheck();
        break;
      // cell is outside of rows 10-14
      default:
        return;
    }
  }
}
```